# Javascript sort array of strings with preference

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array in JavaScript, but I want one specific item to always be first in the sort, and another specific item to always be last:

```
var Person= [{
   "Country": "Japan",
   "Name": "user1"

}, {
   "Country": "Spain",
   "Name": "user24"

}, {
   "Country": "Usa",
   "Name": "user1"

}, {
   "Country": "Brazil",
   "Name": "user1"

}];
```

Here is my `compare` function:

```
function compare(a,b) {
      if (a.Country< b.Country)
        return -1;
      if (a.Country> b.Country)
        return 1;
   //here aditional condition
      if(a.Country=="Spain") //condition for last item
          return 2; 
       if(a.Country=="Brazil") //condition for always in first item
          return -1; 
      return 0;
    }
```

I am running `Person.sort(compare);` to do the sort.

Comment: You need to check for the condition when `b.country == "Spain"` and `b.country == "Brazil"` as well

Comment: …and you need to check for those conditions before the normal comparisons.

Comment: Why don't you just group by country? `Person.reduce(function (o, current) {o[current.Country] = (o[current.Country] || []).concat(current.Name); return o}, {})`.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to check `b` against those strings as well, and second of all, your special comparisons need to come before the general ones.

**Working Live Demo:**

```js
function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.Country == "Spain") return 1;
    if (a.Country == "Brazil") return -1;
    if (b.Country == "Spain") return -1;
    if (b.Country == "Brazil") return 1;
    if (a.Country < b.Country) return -1;
    if (a.Country > b.Country) return 1;
    return 0;
}

var Person = [{
    "Country": "Japan",
        "Name": "user1"

}, {
    "Country": "Spain",
        "Name": "user24"

}, {
    "Country": "Usa",
        "Name": "user1"

}, {
    "Country": "Brazil",
        "Name": "user1"
}];

Person.sort(compare);
console.log(Person);
```

Comment: thanks "the order of the factors does alter the result" :)

Comment: Hi @jearca, do you feel as if I answered your question completely? If so, please don’t forget to mark my answer as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left. If your question hasn't been fully answered, please elaborate on what else you need to know so the community can provide you with further help! Thanks!